# 100 chairs in a circle problem solving with Angular.js and visualization

Tags: javascript, css, angular.js, html5, animation

Here is the problem statement:

> Take a second to imagine that you are in a room with 100 chairs arranged in a circle. These chairs are numbered sequentially from One to One Hundred. At some point in time, the person in chair #1 will be told to leave the room. The person in chair #2 will be skipped, and the person in chair #3 will be told to leave. Next to go is person in chair #6. In other words, 1 person will be skipped initially, and then 2, 3, 4.. and so on. This pattern of skipping will keep going around the circle until there is only one person remaining- The survivor! Note that each chair is removed when the person leaves the room.

Please review my attempt below considering the following points:

1. Correctness (I am getting the winner as # 31)
2. Any chances for optimization

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', [ '$scope', '$interval', '$log', function($scope, $interval, $log){

  $scope.init = function(){
    $scope.people = [];
    $scope.logs = [];

    // get the 100 people/chair
    for(var i=1; i<=100; i++){
      $scope.people.push({ index: i });
    }
  };

  $scope.startFiring = function(){

    var fireIndex = 0, // for removing the person at this index
        skipCount = 0; // for incremental counting 

    if($scope.people.length >= 1){ // if start button clicked again
      $scope.gotWinner = false; // hide the winner
      $interval.cancel(fireInterval); // stop the interval
      $scope.init();
    }

    var fireInterval = $interval(function(){
      
      $scope.disableStartButton = true;

      if ($scope.people.length > 1) { // if more than 1 people
        $scope.logs.push({text: 'Firing #' + $scope.people[fireIndex].index}); // show the log
        
        $scope.people.splice(fireIndex, 1); // fire!
        
        // increment
        skipCount += 1;
        fireIndex += skipCount;

        //if fireIndex becomes greater than $scope.people.length, then set fireIndex to remainder from fireIndex / $scope.people.length
        if(fireIndex > $scope.people.length){
          fireIndex %= $scope.people.length;
        }

      } else {
        $interval.cancel(fireInterval); // stop the interval
        $scope.gotWinner = true; // show the winner
        $scope.disableStartButton = false;
      }
    }, 500); // every 1/2 sec.

  };

  $scope.init(); // intialize the chair/people when the view is loaded or start is clicked again

}]);
```

```css
body{
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

span{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div>
        <span ng-repeat="person in people">{{person.index}}</span>
      </div>
      <button ng-click="startFiring()" ng-disabled="disableStartButton">Start!</button>
      <p ng-show="gotWinner">And the winner is.... # <strong>{{people[0].index}}!</strong></p>
      <p ng-show="logs.length !== 0">Logs:</p>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="log in logs | orderBy:'-'">{{log.text}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The firing sequence you have described (1, 3, 6, 10, 15, …) is different from the typical "Josephus Problem".

Comment: @200_success I have edited the title. However, the problem statement remains the same.

Comment: 31 is correct. [The fiddle could be improved codewise but is correct.](https://jsfiddle.net/n831L7g1/) You can check it by using a smaller number for initialization (instead of `100` set `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mathematical `%` simplification**

Remember that $$a\  \%\   b == a  \ \ if\ b > a$$

I don't know the math, but Python confirms:

```
>>> import random
>>> def random_ints():
    for _ in range(1000): yield random.randint(1, 100)
>>> all(a % b == a for a in random_ints() for b in random_ints() if b > a)
True
```

So:

```
    fireIndex += skipCount;

    //if fireIndex becomes greater than $scope.people.length, then set fireIndex to remainder from fireIndex / $scope.people.length
    if(fireIndex > $scope.people.length){
      fireIndex %= $scope.people.length;
    }
```

can be simplified to

```
fireIndex = (fireIndex + skipCount) % $scope.people.length
```

**Comments**

Some comments are good, but you should avoid writing comments next to obvious code:

```
  if ($scope.people.length > 1) { // if more than 1 people
```

It is already obvious from the code that you are checking if there are more than 1 people, the comment just doubles the effort required to change the code.

The below comment is very confusing instead:

```
if($scope.people.length >= 1){ // if start button clicked again
```

Probably you changed the code but not comment.

Comment: Thank you! What do you think about the correctness? Is `31` correct?